# defaultSource not working as expected at react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How should i put the background image? defaultSource is not working

```
      <Image
        testID="productImage"
        style={styles.productImage}
        source={{ uri: item.images[0].url }}
        defaultSource={require('../../assets/no-photo.png')}
        onError={source => require('../../assets/no-photo.png')}
      />
```

Comment: what you mean by `background image`? is it litterally background image or `placeholder image`?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting images from server, but some images are broken and i need to put an image fallback.

Comment: [Here is an articel](https://reactnativecode.com/show-error-message-if-image-load-failed-react-native/) that i think is relevant to your requirement